# Android Databinding V2 fails for multi-module project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a multi-module Android project, with Kotlin, databinding v2, under Android Studio 3.1.3. Most of my databinding-enabled layouts are enclosed in library modules, which the final application module aggregates.

Problem starts when I want to add new layout in my application module, or override layout from one of library modules. After adding a test layout with `<layout>` tag to the application module, databinding stops generating, with the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
  public static TestBinding bind(@NonNull View view, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                               ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class TestBinding
e: error: cannot generate view binders java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.getMatchingMultiAttributeSetters(SetterStore.java:633)
        at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.getMultiAttributeSetterCalls(SetterStore.java:520)
        at android.databinding.tool.BindingTarget.resolveMultiSetters(BindingTarget.java:220)
        at android.databinding.tool.LayoutBinder.<init>(LayoutBinder.java:256)
        at android.databinding.tool.DataBinder.<init>(DataBinder.java:55)
        at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.ensureDataBinder(CompilerChef.java:95)
        at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:259)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:213)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:111)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:203)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:188)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:90)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:65)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:131)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:87)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:257)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:212)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:95)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:374)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:64)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:405)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:920)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:950)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:404)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

All `DataBindingComponent` interfaces from library modules are being generated, only the one from the application module is not generated.

Comment: For what it's worth, we also use a multi-module project except that we have one library module and multiple app modules. Although we don't usually override library layouts in the app module I've tested it now and it's working perfectly. Only our unit tests are in Kotlin, the rest is Java. Android Studio 3.1.2.

Comment: The root cause of the issue was https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView added as `implementation` dependency to one of the library projects. Changing it to `api` dependency fixed the problem. Strange thing though, as the lib itself doesn't contain any databingings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had similar issue after migrating to `androidx` namespace. Make sure you've updated:

1.your gradle wrapper to `4.10.1` in `gradle-wrapper-properties`

2.you use gradle build plugin `3.3.0-beta-1`

With this configuration everything works fine. Make also sure you don't have any databinding `kapt` or `apt` annotated dependencies in `app.gradle` as since `3.2.0` it is already bundled to gradle